# Need help with essentials permissions group manager

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I'm running a minecraft server, and I want players to be able to use commands like /spawn and /help without opping them.
I've looked on MANY wikis and still, I have no idea how this thing works.
i have downloaded group essentials, and I tried to set up the command, but it doesn't work. Here's the permissions I'm using for default players:

```
groups:
  Default:
    default: true
    permissions:
    - essentials.spawn
    - essentials.helpop
    - essentials.help
    - essentials.rules
    - essentials.list
    inheritance:
    - g:groupmanager_default
    - g:bukkit_default
    - g:essentials_default
    - g:towny_default
    info:
      prefix: '&e'
      build: false
      suffix: ''
```

Comment: Minecraft server permissions can be a mess. It would be great to have an updated, comprehensive answer to this question! So much of the information out there is either outdated, or too specific to be useful.

Answer (score 1):

For the `/help` command, add the permissions `minecraft.command.help` and `bukkit.command.help`**.**

For the `/spawn` command, add the permission `essentials.spawn`**.**

If you want, here are the links to 2 wikis that list all the Essentials permissions and all the Minecraft permissions:

> [Default Minecraft Permissions](http://wiki.bukkit.org/CraftBukkit_Commands)
>
> [Essentials Permissions](http://wiki.ess3.net/doc/permissions)